# Refactor for-loop with side effects to stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to refactor a Java 7 code to Java 8.

Here the Java 7 code:

```
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();
for (B b : bList) {
    D d = new D(b.getSomeWhat());
    d.setDisabled(true);
    aList.add(d);
}
```

I try this one in Java 8:

```
bList.stream().map(b -> {
    D d = new new D(b.getSomeWhat());
    d.setDisabled(true);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have a `missisng return statement` error.

How can I write the code with Java 8 streams?

Comment: add 'return d;' after  'd.setDisabled(true);'

Comment: btw... don't try too hard to rewrite your whole code to `Java 8`. The code you have shown should probably not be touched, if it's that simple. The stream solution by the way isn't any simpler, just a bit slower ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return `d` in your mapping:

```
bList.stream().map(b -> {
    D d = new D(b.getSomeWhat());
    d.setDisabled(true);
    return d;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Remove second `new` from `D d = new new D(b.getSomeWhat());`

Comment: You can also break this apart into two pipeline steps: The first one a `map` creating `D`s, the second one a `peek` which calls `setDisabled(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

1. using `() - {}` construct requires return statement,
2. `d.setDisabled(true)` returns void.

You could do something like this:

```
    bList.stream()
        .map(B::getSomeWhat)
        .map(D::new)
        .map(d -> {
            d.setDisabled(true);
            return d;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of that final `map`, you can do [`peek(b -> b.setDisables(true))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: good that the `peek`-javadoc was linked... that should of course be read before applying `peek` :-)